# Haftara Without Minyan

Tags: haftarah

When davening alone one should read Kriat HaTorah without the Brachot from a Chumash. When doing the same on a day when the Haftara is read, should one also read the Haftara but omit the Brachot, should one completely omit the Haftara, or should one read it with the Brachot?

Comment: How do you know your first sentence is true? Please edit your post to justify this motivating premise. I mean, why not ask about the Torah reading part too?

Comment: What do you mean "omit the Haftara"? One can pick up a nach and read some, whenever.

Comment: You certainly should not say berachot on haftara unless it was preceded by Keriat hatorah from a sefer torah. See Rema OC 284:1

Answer (score 1):

The accepted halacha is that without a minyan one should not say a brachah the source is.   Talmud, Megillah ibid.

There is no issue with reading the Haftorah and it would be nice to read it.

I can't find a source saying that it's required for the individual to read the Haftorah if there is no minyan. There is for sure no problem if one reads it without the Brachot.

Comment: On which page in Talmud Megillah can I find that ruling?

Comment: it can be found on daf 24

Comment: another source is shulchan aruch 284-3

Comment: לֹא נִתְקְנָה הַהַפְטָרָה אֶלָּא בְּצִבּוּרכ,9 אַחַר שֶׁקָּרְאוּ בְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרָה,כא אֲבָל אִם לֹא קָרְאוּ בְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרָה אֶלָּא בְּחֻמָּשׁ בְּלֹא בְרָכָה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁנִּתְבָּאֵר בְּסִמָּן קמ"גכב,10 – לֹא יֹאמַר הַהַפְטָרָה עִם בִּרְכוֹתֶיהָ.11 אֲבָל בְּלֹא בִרְכוֹתֶיהָ יְכוֹלִים לְאָמְרָהּ.כג וְנָכוֹן הַדָּבָר שֶׁיֹּאמְרוּהָ,כד שֶׁלֹּא תִשְׁתַּכַּח לָהֶם תּוֹרַת הַהַפְטָרָה.כה

אֲבָל אִם קָרָא בְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרָה פָּסוּל,12 וְעַל דֶּרֶךְ שֶׁנִּתְבָּאֵר בְּסִמָּן קמ"גכו – יֹאמְרוּ הַהַפְטָרָה עִם בִּרְכוֹתֶיהָ,כז 13כְּמוֹ שֶׁנִּתְבָּאֵר שָׁם:כח,